# Headsets mic not working on skype Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, skype, microphone

I have a problem using skype and my headset, I'm using `ubuntu 19.10` and `skype` is on `version 8.58.0.93` the headsets I'm using is `Aventree ANC032` my problem is that my bluetooth headset's mic is not working in skype, to make it work, I have to go into sound settings and change my output configuration to  `Headset Head Unit(HSP/HFP)` and change my input device to my headset mic, it will then work but the sound is changed to mono and it sounds terrible, when the call is done, I need to change the output configration back to `High Fidelity Playback(A2DP Sink)` to get better sound quality where you can actually hear something, changing configurations in skype itself does nothing.

Sometimes the above method doesn't work and I need to unpair my headset and pair it again, then change the configuration in my sound settings

It's very annoying to do this each time I need to take or make a call.

How can I change/fix this, to keep my sterio sound but still have my mic work?

Comment: Try this, go to your mixer, split the channels, lower one side right or left to zero and set the other side to about -30db (this works for my mic). This worked after I tried different kernels and distros. My internal mic and bluetooth work with this setting now. You may need to tweak the channel, I used a skype test call so I could hear my recording while I found the best setting.

Answer (score -1):

First, turn off your headset. then turn it back on, let it pair, click on the bluetooth manager icon in the system tray, select Devices, see if you can see this device, if it is automatically paired, make sure it is connected as an "Audio Sink". If not, right click on the device, remove the current connection, and then right click again, and connect to "Audio sink".

then, play a youtube video or anything that has audio output, go to pulse audio control, see if you can select this device, and see if you can hear anything. if you have poor audio quality, maybe your headphone is defective. try to pair with your phone and see if it play audio properly.

I have been using two bluetooth headphones (1 earplug) with my Ubuntu 16.04 for skype/zoom calls with no issue. Occasionally it could not automatically pair or won't list it, but dock the headphone and undock it often make it visible to the system again.

if everything works fine, open your skype, goto Tools\Audio video settings and choose this device. basically the audio input/output list in skype will look the same as the pulse audio devices.